# marking a WinForms Button as serializable

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization

This is my very first program for serialization.

An error occurred when trying to serialize a button control.

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     CheckSerialization();                
     Button btn = btnSerialized;            
}

public void CheckSerialization()
{
     Stream write = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\ser.bin");
     BinaryFormatter serial = new BinaryFormatter();
     serial.Serialize(write, btnSerialized);
     write.Close();
}

private void btnSerialized_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\ser.bin",FileMode.Open);
     BinaryFormatter bf= new BinaryFormatter();
     object obj = bf.Deserialize(fs);
     Button button12 = (Button)obj;
     button1 = button12;
     button1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
}
```

> Type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' in Assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.**

How do I mark this object as serializable?

Comment: Check this out - this might help - Surrogate Serialization - http://www.codeproject.com/kb/dotnet/Surrogate_Serialization.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the line that looks like `public partial class Form1 : Form`.
Right above it, place `[Serializable]`. That marks your class for serialization.
You will need to control your own serialization however, since as noted below, UI objects do not serialize. For that, look at the [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) interface.

More information about SerializableAttribute is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You don't. The type must be marked as Serializable, not the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't serialize Winforms objects (or other UI objects, generally speaking)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to export the object or reload the object with user provided property values for dynamicity then why don't you use `System.Reflection`? Here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime