# How to serialize GraphicPath or Region data

Tags: c#, object, serialization

I'm trying to serialize my custom control's final state.

Reason is I do bunch of stuff to obtain final state, but its takes too much time and source during run-time, and I don't have any other way to go. So I want to do it once, serialize it and use serialized form as a template to avoid waste of sources.

Important thing for me is to serialize Region data of related object. But following code causes exception. I'm new to serialization stuff so please explain your ideas.

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Serialized_t1.Data", FileMode.Create);
BinaryFormatter processor = new BinaryFormatter();
processor.Serialize(stream, object1);
stream.Close();
```

Note: Class of related custom control marked like this:

```
[Serializable]
[Designer(typeof(TControllDesigner))]
public class TControl: UserControl
```

Note 2 : Exception is

```
{"Type 'System.Windows.Forms.UserControl' in Assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable."}
```

Note 3/Edit : 
I noticed that GraphicPath or Region causes exception during serialization, so should I need different approach or what ?

Comment: And the exception is.....?

Comment: The exception is pretty clear - `UserControl` is not marked as `Serializable`.  You might want to try serializing just the region data rather than the whole control.

Comment: I already mark related class with [Serializable] tag, what else I should do ?

Comment: this might help you in solution [saving button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597472/marking-a-winforms-button-as-serializable)

Comment: I need to serialize Graphicpath or region data of object, trying to impelement separated new class , initialize objects values to new class to avoid "Custom user control objects can not serialized" problem(thats what people said on forums) but still same exception. Can someone give example of code how to do it ?