# C# Windows Forms - Preserving data in dynamically created objects

Tags: c#, preserve

I'm currently working on a windows form application in C# and was wondering how to preserve data between executions? My application starts with a blank form that has a button that dynamically creates user controls, each one just containing a text box (picture a to-do list). The user has the ability to write into these text boxes, as well as dynamically delete them as well.

I've got the application all built and I can create number of objects, but I was wondering how I could save the data between closing and re-opening it. This is in VS 2015.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at [serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656716.aspx)

Comment: You have to load the data (do you have models or data-classes?) on startup, update-and-save the data when the user changes anything. The storage mechanism can be anything, a database, file...

Comment: @hankide You assume there is anything to serialize. A user-control or textbox can't be serialized.

Comment: It's call a database.  The most simplified version being just a text file.

Comment: Since you only seem to need to store the Texts in the TextBoxes the issue is rather trivial, isn't it? Seriliaze the texts as a List<string> and on startup deserialize it again. Then create one of your UCs for each string in the list! 20-30 lines of code altogether..

Comment: Code to save: `List<string> texts = new List<string>();
            foreach (Control ctl in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
                foreach (Control ct in ctl.Controls)
                    if (ct is TextBox) texts.Add(ct.Text);
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(texts.GetType());
            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\texts.xml"))
            {
                xs.Serialize(tw, texts);
                tw.Close();
            }`

Comment: Code to load: `List<string> texts = new List<string>();
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(texts.GetType());
            using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"d:\texts.xml"))
            {
                texts = (List<string>)xs.Deserialize(tr);
                tr.Close();
            }
            foreach (string t in texts)
            {
                UserControl uc = UcText(t);
                uc.Parent = flowLayoutPanel1;
                flowLayoutPanel1.SetFlowBreak(uc, true);
           
            }`

Comment: `UserControl UcText(string text)` is a function that creates one of your user controls and fills the TextBox with a string. Do reuse it in the button click that the users has to add the UCs !

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would suggest making a list of your textboxes and then serializing **their values** and then saving into some format, let's say xml. It is possible to serialize whole list and then load it with simple code.

Edit: Maarten had a good point, I forgot about that you cannot serialize the whole component. I am assuming you are adding textboxes dynamically, so you already have some list/array of values.

Comment: This would work if you make a *list of the values in your textboxes*, not a list of your textboxes.

Comment: Where did you get this @Maarten ? You can serialize even your own classes

Comment: Because neither [System.Windows.Forms.Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx) nor [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) either implements `ISerializable` or is marked with the `[Serializable]` attribute. Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597472/marking-a-winforms-button-as-serializable). You can't serialize WinForms UI objects.

Comment: @Maarten you are right, I completely forgot about it, edited answer

Comment: Nonsense, any property you set can be serialized one way or another. So there really is no other issue than writing out the serialization/deserialization code. The usual way is to create serializable shadow classes. You will have to know which properties you do need, though.. Remeber, they are set in code so you can save them! Serializing enumeration values will avoid any magic numbers..

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you've got two options.

1. Store to file.
2. Store to DB.

Depending on your circumstances, privileges etc. you might want to call a web service and feed the state information to it. Then, upon re-launch, you just get read back from it.

Or, if that's a good option, you can simply store a local file with the information and then read from it. The exchangeability of data will suffer and you may face issues with access rights, though.

If the amount information that you need to store is fairly limited, you might simply write a few keys to the registry. The info will still be local and access needs to be granted but except for that, you'd be compartmentilize the data rather well.